# Bash command does not work in script but in console

Tags: bash

I have running the two commands in a script where I want to check if all files in a directoy are media:

```
1 All_LINES=$(ls -1 | wc -l)
2 echo "Number of lines: ${All_LINES}"
3
4 REACHED_LINES=$(ls -1 *(*.JPG|*.jpg|*.PNG|*.png|*.JPEG|*.jpeg) | wc -l)
5 echo "Number of reached lines: ${REACHED_LINES}"

if[...]
```

Running line 4 and 5 sequentially in a shell it works as expected, counting all files ending with .jpg, .JPG...

Running all together in a script gives the following error though:

```
Number of lines: 12
/home/andreas/.bash_scripts/rnimgs: command substitution: line 17: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/home/andreas/.bash_scripts/rnimgs: command substitution: line 17: `ls -1 *(*.JPG|*.jpg|*.PNG|*.png|*.JPEG|*.jpeg) | wc -l)'
Number of reached lines:
```

Could somebody explain this to me, please?

EDIT: This is as far as I got:

```
#!/bin/bash

# script to rename images, sorted by "type" and "date modified" and named by current folder

#get/set basename for files
CURRENT_BASENAME=$(basename "${PWD}")
echo -e "Current directory/basename is: ${CURRENT_BASENAME}\n"
read -e -p "Please enter basename: " -i "${CURRENT_BASENAME}" BASENAME
echo -e "\nNew basename is: ${BASENAME}\n"

#start
echo -e "START RENAMING"

#get nr of all files in directory
All_LINES=$(ls -1 | wc -l)
echo "Number of lines: ${All_LINES}"

#get nr of media files in directory
REACHED_LINES=$(ls -1 *(*.JPG|*.jpg|*.PNG|*.png|*.JPEG|*.jpeg) | wc -l)
echo "Number of reached lines: ${REACHED_LINES}"
```

EDIT1: Thanks again guys, this is my result so far. Still room for improvement, but a start and ready to test.

```
#!/bin/bash

#script to rename media files to a choosable name (default: ${basename} of current directory) and sorted by date modified

#config
media_file_extensions="(*.JPG|*.jpg|*.PNG|*.png|*.JPEG|*.jpeg)"

#enable option extglob (extended globbing): If set, the extended pattern matching features described above under Pathname Expansion are enabled.
#more info: https://askubuntu.com/questions/889744/what-is-the-purpose-of-shopt-s-extglob
#used for regex
shopt -s extglob

#safe and set IFS (The Internal Field Separator): IFS is used for word splitting after expansion and to split lines into words with the read builtin command.
#more info: https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/$IFS
#used to get blanks in filenames
SAVEIFS=$IFS;
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b");

#get and print current directory
basedir=$PWD
echo "Directory:" $basedir

#get and print nr of files in current directory
all_files=( "$basedir"/* )
echo "Number of files in directory: ${#all_files[@]}"

#get and print nr of media files in current directory
media_files=( "$basedir"/*${media_file_extensions} )
echo -e "Number of media files in directory: ${#media_files[@]}\n"

#validation if #all_files = #media_files
if [ ${#all_files[@]} -ne ${#media_files[@]} ]
then
  echo "ABORT - YOU DID NOT REACH ALL FILES, PLEASE CHECK YOUR FILE ENDINGS"
  exit
fi

#make a copy
backup_dir="backup_95f528fd438ef6fa5dd38808cdb10f"
backup_path="${basedir}/${backup_dir}"
mkdir "${backup_path}"
rsync -r "${basedir}/" "${backup_path}" --exclude "${backup_dir}"
echo "BACKUP MADE"

echo -e "START RENAMING"

#set new basename
basename=$(basename "${PWD}")
read -e -p "Please enter file basename: " -i "$basename" basename
echo -e "New basename is: ${basename}\n"

#variables
counter=1;
new_name="";
file_extension="";

#iterate over files
for f in $(ls -1 -t -r *${media_file_extensions})
do
  #catch file name
  echo "Current file is:           $f"
  #catch file extension
  file_extension="${f##*.}";
  echo "Current file extension is: ${file_extension}"
  #create new name
  new_name="${basename}_${counter}.${file_extension}"
  echo "New name is:               ${new_name}";
  #rename file
  mv $f "${new_name}";
  echo -e "Counter is:                ${counter}\n"

  ((counter++))
done

#get and print nr of media files before
echo "Number of media files before: ${#media_files[@]}"
#get and print nr of media files after
media_files=( "$basedir"/*${media_file_extensions} )
echo -e "Number of media files after: ${#media_files[@]}\n"

#delete backup?
while true; do
    read -p "Do you wish to keep the result? " yn
    case $yn in
        [Yy]* ) rm -r ${backup_path}; echo "BACKUP DELETED"; break ;;
        [Nn]* ) rm -r !(${backup_dir}); rsync -r "${backup_path}/" "${basedir}"; rm -r ${backup_path}; echo "BACKUP RESTORED THEN DELETED"; break;; 
        * ) echo "Please answer yes or no.";;
    esac
done

#reverse IFS to default
IFS=$SAVEIFS;

echo -e "END RENAMING"
```

Comment: Show the complete script

Comment: you probably nned to escape some characthers in the `REACHED_LINES=$(ls -1 *(*.JPG|*.jpg|*.PNG|*.png|*.JPEG|*.jpeg) | wc -l)`

Comment: You are using extended globs, which you probably enabled with `shopt -s extglob` in your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`. Your script ignores those files, so you need to enable them again explicitly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to and don't want to use `ls` at all here. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Also, don't use uppercase for your private variables. See [Correct Bash and shell script variable capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization)

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s extglob

read -e -p "Please enter basename: " -i "$PWD" basedir
all_files=( "$basedir"/* )
echo "Number of files: ${#all_files[@]}"

media_files=( "$basedir"/*(*.JPG|*.jpg|*.PNG|*.png|*.JPEG|*.jpeg) )
echo "Number of media files: ${#media_files[@]}"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, especially for the sources.

Answer (score 3):

As @chepner already pointed out in a comment, you likely need to explicitly enable extended globbing on your script. c.f. [Greg's WIKI](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob)

It's also possible to condense that pattern to eliminate some redundancy and add mixed case if you like -

```
$: ls -1 *.*([Jj][Pp]*([Ee])[Gg]|[Pp][Nn][Gg])
a.jpg
b.JPG
c.jpeg
d.JPEG
mixed.jPeG
mixed.pNg
x.png
y.PNG
```

You can also accomplish this without `ls`, which is error-prone. Try this:

```
$: all_lines=(*)
$: echo ${#all_lines[@]}
55

$: reached_lines=( *.*([Jj][Pp]*([Ee])[Gg]|[Pp][Nn][Gg]) )
$: echo ${#reached_lines[@]}
8
```

c.f. [this breakdown](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)

If all you want is counts, but prefer not to include directories:

```
all_dirs=( */ )
num_files=$(( ${#all_files[@]} - ${#all_dirs[@]} ))
```

If there's a chance you will have a directory with a name that matches your jpg/png pattern, then it gets trickier. At that point it's probably easier to just use @markp-fuso's solution.

One last thing - avoid all-caps variable names. Those are generally reserved for system stuff.

## edit

If you're using `shopt` for `extglob` anyway, you might as well use it.
`shopt -s nocaseglob` makes the whole case-insensitive pattern simpler:
`*.*(jp*(e)g|png)` will do it.

Also, if you were going to something like

```
num_files=$(( ${#all_files[@]} - ${#all_dirs[@]} ))
```

then you should also probably use `nullglob` when loading the array so that zero is possible and accurate, or at least `failglob`. "Hidden" files and directories beginning with a dot are generally excluded, which might be a bug or a feature, according to your needs; if you want them included, add `dotglob`.

If for some reason you wanted to check arbitrary depth subdirectories as well, set `globstar` and use `**` instead of just `*` for the directory pattern - e.g., `$basedir/**/*.*(jp*(e)g|png)` - and remember that `*()` in extended globbing is "zero or more", while `+()` is "one or more", `?()` is "zero or one", etc.

Reads more [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the OP wants to limit the counts to normal **files** (ie, exclude non-files like directories, pipes, symbolic links, etc), a solution based on `find` may provide more accurate counts.

Updating OP's original code to use `find` (ignoring dot files for now):

```
ALL_LINES=$(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | wc -l)
echo "Number of lines: ${ALL_LINES}"

REACHED_LINES=$(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f \( -iname '*.jpg' -o -iname '*.png' -o -iname '*.jpeg' \) | wc -l)
echo "Number of reached lines: ${REACHED_LINES}"
```